# How to find out the proper overridden method in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, overriding

I have one interface `I1` which defines a method `M1`. Two other classes `C1` and `C2` are implementing `I1` and over-rides `M1`.

In another class `C3` I have a reference to `M1`. Now how will I understand if `M1` is referring to `C1_M1` or `C2_M1`?

`P.S` I can find it out while debugging the code. But I am looking for some shortcut without executing it.

Comment: who puts the object there?

Comment: @LuísSoares I only see the reference there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you created object in this way

```
I1 i=new c1();
```

then `i.m1()` will call m1 method  of `class c1`

if

```
  I1 i=new c2();
```

then `i.m1()` will call m1 method  of `class c2`

If you don't know how the object is created and you have only the reference then Sorry to Say you can only find it at runtime as it is [Run time Polymorphism](http://www.javatpoint.com/runtime-polymorphism-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

It is run time polymorphism so you are able to understand it at run time only.

If you know what will be the input to your program then you can understand which class instance reference came.

```
interface A{

}

class B implements A{

}

class C implements A{

}

class Main{

  public static void main(String args[]){

    // input
    Object o = new B();  // just assume your logic give you object B. 

    if(o instanceof B){
       B b = (B) o;
     // invoke methods 
    }else if(o instanceof C){
      C c = (C) o;
     // invoke methods
    }
  }

}
```

In above code you are able to understand that class `B` methods will be invoked.

Summary of all is - you have to understand your code, recognize the inputs and then you are able to understand which class will be called at run time. otherwise debugging is best practice.

Comment: Do you mean `B b = (B) o;` rather than `o = new B();` (and the same for `C`)?